# Create .pem-file results in "file or folder not found."

Tags: openssl, debian, ssl-certificate, pem, mail-server

After creating a .key- and a .csr-file by following the steps of [this tutorial](http://appbead.com/blog/how-to-setup-mail-server-on-debian-8-jessie-with-postfix-dovecot-1.html) (Step: **Prepare SSL Certificate**) it's not possible to do `sudo sed -i -e '$a\' appbead.com.pem`. I get the error "file or folder not found". So I created the file and tried it again, but nothing happens - meaning, no data was written into the .pem-file I manually created.

Answer (score 0):

The file `appbead.com.pem` does not exist in current directory. That's it. Most probably a previous step, that should create it, did not.

Comment: Ah, now I got it. I have to simply save the .csr-file to .pem and the command `sudo sed -i -e '$a\' appbead.com.pem` adds the _new line_, mentioned in the tutorial.